# can't connect to mongdb nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i'm facing some issue when trying to connect to mongodb using my nodejs app.
heres the code

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

async function main() {
  const uri =
    "mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx.uj545.mongodb.net/xxxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  await client.connect();
  await listDatabases(client);
  try {
    await client.connect();
    await listDatabases(client);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

and heres the Output:

```
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT xxxx.uj545.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'xxxx.uj545.mongodb.net'
}
```

But when I tried to do a test connection with Mongodb Compass, I got the same problem.

then I tried Mongodb Compass using Windows VPS from the Google Cloud Platform, and it worked,

then, where did it go wrong?

the device that I use is Macbook Air early 2015 with MacOs mojave

Comment: maybe the problem is in network access configuration in mongodb settings

Comment: I have set the config to accept all incoming ip addresses [0.0.0.0/0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you not to use raw connection instead you can use mongoose as an ODM to work with it
here is the ref [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198421/mongo-db-node-js-some-error-with-db-being-undefined/64199434#64199434)

Answer (score 0):

If you create the db in mongodb cloud, you need to configure the ip address in Network Access in the mongodb cloud panel.

use 0.0.0.0/0 if you want to allow access from any ip, or enter your ip.

Comment: i have done with thats, but i still facing the same issue

Comment: ok, try to remove "+srv" from uri.
or in connection form of your cluster select "connect your application" and select "nodejs" and use "2.2.12 or later" like version for generate the uri.